# HTML tables should be hidden when checkbox already checked by default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As a default, the checkbox is already checked but the tables are not hidden. As a default, the first two table shall be demonstrated. When you click on a few times, you can see hidden tables but they should be hidden as default checked. Do I need to call function? or Do I need to change parameter in function?

```js
function showMe(cls) {
    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
        if (chboxs[i].checked) {
            vis = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    for (let e of elements) {
        if (vis === 1) {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'table';
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="c1" checked="true" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
        <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
            <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
        </td>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
            <font color="gray">N/A</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
            <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
        </td>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
            <font color="gray">N/A</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to call `showMe('box')` when the page loads:

```js
function showMe(cls) {
  var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
  var vis = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
    if (chboxs[i].checked) {
      vis = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
  for (let e of elements) {
    if (vis === 1) {
      e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      e.style.display = 'table';
    }
  }
}

showMe('box');
```

```html
<table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <input type="checkbox" name="c1" checked="true" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
    <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
      <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
    </td>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
      <font color="gray">N/A</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
      <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
    </td>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
      <font color="gray">N/A</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

However the far better approach is to remove the inline `onclick` event handler, and bind an unobtrusive `change` event handler to the checkboxes instead. Then you can simply trigger that event when the page loads.

Note that this approach has the benefit of making the first loop in your code redundant. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.show').on('change', e => {
    var targetClass = $(e.target).data('targetclass');
    $('.' + targetClass).toggle();   
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <input type="checkbox" name="c1" checked="true" class="show" data-targetclass="box">Show Result
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
    <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
      <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
    </td>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
      <font color="gray">N/A</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
      <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
    </td>
    <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
      <font color="gray">N/A</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
        <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
        <font color="gray">N/A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

As an aside, you should remove the inline CSS styling, along with the `width`, `bordercolor`, `cellpadding` etc. attributes, and use an external stylesheet. In addition `font` elements have been deprecated for a very long time and should never be used.

Comment: Where shall I put it showMe('box')? You said when the page is loaded. I put it after function but it didnt work. Because I am using css  to write showMe('box') function in Html

Comment: Without seeing your page it's hard to say exactly. However simply calling it from a `<script>` block in your HTML (after you've defined the function) should work

Comment: I put it inside <script showMe('box') </script> But it didnt work again. The html data is too much, might it be a problem ?

Comment: Basically, I am launching the HTML file as test.html. Therefore, I added the showMe('box') after function in javascript but it didnt work. I am not able to show because it is 8.500Kb

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details, I prepared as a html file. It is not working when I call showMe('box') in javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function showMe(cls) {
    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
        if (chboxs[i].checked) {
            vis = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    for (let e of elements) {
        if (vis === 1) {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'table';
        }

    }
}
show('box');
</script>

</head>


                <br>
                <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <input type="checkbox" name="c1" checked="true" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                
                <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
                <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px"align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody></table></table>

</html>
```